# Can I use a spatially lagged Dependent Variable while using Spatial Error Model?

Tags: regression, spatial, autoregressive, lagrange-multipliers

I have following issue:

I run spatial diagnostics on dependencies for my Log-Log Transformed regression model. LM Tests (including Robust) are highly significant.

Since I am using GeoDa, I cannot run robust Error or Lag models because it is not an option. I thought of manually creating a spatially lagged Y and include it in the Spatial Error model. Likelihood ratio test says it's much better than just using either one.

Is this approach valid or is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but that's essentially the Spatial Durbin Model, now. Looks like the equation below:

```
y = ρWy + Xβ + θWX + u
```

SDM synthesizes the advantages of a spatial lag model and a spatial error model. You can work your way back to both models: for the lag, if θ = 0; and for error, if θ = -ρβ.

GeoDa is great for visualizations, but not regression modeling. Use R, STATA, Python or MATLAB.

For more depth in the math logic, see the following:

- http://rei.revues.org/3887 : One of the more popular articles on the subject, by James P. Lesage
- http://www.atlantis-press.com/php/download_paper.php?id=25840534
- Golgher, A. B., & Voss, P. R. (2016). How to interpret the coefficients of spatial models: Spillovers, direct and indirect effects. Spatial Demography, 4(3), 175-205.